# How to add a script that runs from the OS X menubar

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm using ssh extensively and I want to be able to click on a button on the OS X menubar that opens the Terminal and does:

```
ssh -p myport myserver
```

Such that I only have to type in my password, and keeps the terminal open until I exit the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Open *AppleScript Editor* and paste the following script:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "ssh -p myport myserver"
end tell
```

Save it in `~/Library/Scripts`. Then download [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) and run it—it will show your script right in the menu bar:

[image]

Comment: You can, in fact, show the system-wide script menu in the menubar (and add and subtract to its contents as desired) by opening AppleScript Editor and in the first pane of its Preferences, check "Show Script Menu in Menubar."

Comment: True, it's a little hidden. I prefer FastScripts for the ability to set shortcuts right away.

Comment: Yeah, I know, and that is cool. I should have added, the main virtue of the system menu is, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

[Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) could be exactly what you are looking for. (I am not affiliated with the developer in any way.)

Answer (score 0):

[Xbar](https://xbarapp.com/) works nicely for that, you just need to follow the submenu example and define menu items like this:

```bash
echo "Run"
echo "---"

echo "Menu Item"
echo "--Submenu Item | shell=my_app | param1=--arg | terminal=true"
```